# jQuery toggle DIV - Reset toggle when element is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm trying to implement a slide out menu and I'm having trouble cancelling the toggle effect when the full panel is click.

I use the Menu anchor to initialize the toggle. When the slide out menu appears, the opacity of the full panel drops. I want for the user to simply click anywhere on the full panel to cancel the toggle and return to the original state.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q2tcE/

jQuery:

```
$('.menu-nav').toggle(

function () {

    $('.full_panel').animate({
        width: "75%",
        opacity: 0.20
    }, 500);

    $('.aside-panel').animate({
        width: "25%"
    }, 500);

},

function () {

    $('.full_panel').animate({
        width: "100%",
        opacity: 1
    }, 500);

    $('.aside-panel').animate({
        width: "0%"
    }, 500);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="header"></div>

<div class="full_panel">
    <a href="#" class="menu-nav">Menu</a>
</div>

<div class="aside-panel"></div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body{height: 100%; margin: 0; background:#2980b9 }

.header{background: #BADA55; padding: 20px; background: #2980b9}

.full_panel{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.aside-panel{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    width: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.clearfix{clear: both}

a{color: #CCC; text-decoration: none; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply make use of two functions:

```
   function togglePanel() {
    $('.menu-nav').toggle(
    function () {
        $('.full_panel').animate({
            width: "75%",
            opacity: 0.20
        }, 500);
        $('.aside-panel').animate({
            width: "25%"
        }, 500);
    },
    function () {
        $('.full_panel').animate({
            width: "100%",
            opacity: 1
        }, 500);
        $('.aside-panel').animate({
            width: "0%"
        }, 500);
    });
}
function togglePanelReverse() {
    $('.full_panel').animate({
        width: "100%",
        opacity: 1
    }, 500);
    $('.aside-panel').animate({
        width: "0%"
    }, 500);
}
$('.full_panel').click(function () {
    togglePanelReverse();
});
togglePanel();
```

Comment: This is a good start, thanks! The only issue is that the slide out panel shouldn't close unless the .full-panel is clicked. If I click anywhere on the screen (header or in the slide panel) then it closes. It should ONLY close and reset when clicking the .full_panel

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a click-Handler to the div You want to toggle back:

```
$('.menu-nav').toggle(function () {
  $('.full_panel').animate({
    width: "75%",
    opacity: 0.20
  }, 500);

  $('.aside-panel').animate({
    width: "25%"
  }, 500);
```

});

```
$('.full_panel').click(function() {  
    $('.full_panel').animate({
        width: "100%",
        opacity: 1
    }, 500);
    $('.aside-panel').animate({
        width: "0%"
    }, 500);
});
```